# Cant pass param in for $.ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have following ajax call:

```
  var empId = $(this).attr('name').replace(/disp/,'');
   $.ajax({
      url: '<%= Url.Action( "AjaxDisp" ) %>',
      data: { id: empId, format: 'json' },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data,status) {
         // populate the popup and display it            
      }
   });
```

empId is there(I use alert(empId); to test it, it it okay). But in action method AjaxDisp(int id, strng format), I can get the id, but I can get format = "json".

Why?

Comment: Can you show the post header an content as displayed in firebug?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the object (passed to data) to JSON string.

```
 var empId = $(this).attr('name').replace(/disp/,'');
   $.ajax({
      url: '<%= Url.Action( "AjaxDisp" ) %>',
      data: JSON.stringify({ id: empId, format: 'json' }), //converting your object to JSON string.
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data,status) {
         // populate the popup and display it            
      }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks. When try it and run it. It said JSON is not defined.

Comment: The native JSON parser is available in Internet Explorer 8 and FireFox 3.1+ For other browsers, you'll need the JSON library.